# how to use Band Pass filter(18Khz to 22Khz) in Android

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, frequency

I need to use Band Pass Filter to filter my real time recording audio. The Range is about 18Khz to 22Khz. I've seen many examples,unfortunatly they are used to detect frequency of audio....Since i'm new to DSP,please ellobrate your answer....