# Real time audio processing in Android phones

Tags: android, audio, real-time

I need to make real time audio processing for Android phones (with delay lower than 9ms). 
I need to get sound from the microphone and from the **line input** (therefore I also need line-in adapter for phone). What technologies or libraries can do this?

Comment: The answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456630/how-to-use-band-pass-filter18khz-to-22khz-in-android has a link to a library that might be useful.

Comment: I do not need a filter, I need only a library for real time audio processing

Comment: Then you should consider changing the title of your post as it specifically mentions filtering. If you want to read from the mic or line input have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

Comment: Can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184352/android-accessibility-service-real-time-audio-processing question